# Percentage point of Normal Distribution.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Let $$X \sim N(65,64)     $$ Find the lower $2$% point for $X$; that is, find the value of $x$ such that $Pr(X<x) = 0.02   $

i know i need to do something like $\frac{X- 65 }8 = ...    $ but not too sure what??

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with doing something like $\dfrac{X-65}{8}$.

Since $X\sim N(65, 64)$, then $\dfrac{X-65}{8} \sim N(0,1)$. It is easy to see that 
$$Pr(X < x)=Pr\left(\dfrac{X-65}{8}<\dfrac{x-65}{8}\right)=Pr\left(Z<\dfrac{x-65}{8}\right)=0.02$$

where $Z$ is standard normal distributed.

The quantile of a standard normal distribution can be found in many introductory books or some statistical software such as R. You will find out that $Pr(Z<-2.054) = 0.02$. From that, you can easily solve for $x$.

Comment: so $\frac {X-65}8 = -2.054$ hence $x= 48.568$ ???

Comment: is that correct?

Comment: @jill I think that's correct.